# Кастомные поля в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я создал собственный тип записи "Speakers".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К етой записи с помощью плагина Advanced Custom Fields, я создал группу полей "Event Schedule":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что сейчас я могу заполнить только одну группу, а мне нужно таких групп неограниченое количество.

Вопрос в том можно ли добавить кнопку например "Добавить еще группу", и была возможность снова заполнить поля? Возможно есть решение с помощью другого плагина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом плагине есть "Повторитель":

> Поле «Повторитель» позволяет создать набор вложенных полей, которые
>   можно повторять снова и снова во время редактирования содержимого!

Создаёте повторитель и в него вкладывайте свои поля. Ниже этих полей появится кнопка "Добавить ещё". Повторитель будет возвращать массив с данными. Документация и видео [здесь](http://acf.wp-book.ru/povtoritel/).

Спасибо @eugene_v. Действительно "повторитель" включен в pro версию. В бесплатной нет.

Comment: Только повторитель есть в Pro версии если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: @eugene_v pro версия бесплатно на гитхабе лежит.

Comment: У меня есть pro версия, просто люди которые будут читать ваш ответ, могут не найти это в acf, поэтому стоит уточнить что повторитель есть в pro версии

Comment: @eugene_v спасибо, добавил в ответ.